# TN VISA Tax+ Spouse F1 Visa Taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, tn-visa

My husband is a Canadian citizen and he is working in USA on a TN visa. I am in Canada on a Work Permit and I am not a PR yet. I have two questions:

1. Am I considered as a tie for my husband to Canada in terms of tax? Shall he pay taxes to both US and Canada?
2. I have an offer from a University in USA to both work as a researcher on campus and earn my PhD, If I go to USA on a F1 visa, how is it for my husband an I in terms of tax?

I am asking since I know I can study on TD visa but I cannot work on campus in the University.